# mosquitto (mqtt broker) is refusing connections over websockets

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I've set up a mosquitto broker but it refuses to connect over websockets
here is my conf file:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883 0.0.0.0 

listener 8008 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets
```

and I don't have any conf at conf.d

Using the PAHO javascript client I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

by the way I'm using debian jessie as OS

-------------------------------------EDIT 1----------------------------------

I've lowered the iptables and it still not working.
The usual way to connect is working (with port 1883)
Here is the output when I start mosquitto

```
1477788244: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Thu, 25 Aug 2016 10:12:09 +0100) starting
1477788244: Using default config.
1477788244: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1477788244: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the same machine as the broker or from a different machine? Also do you have a firewall enabled?

Comment: The test machine is diferent from broker one, since the normal way (not websocket) is working, i'll check for iptables to see if its blocking

Comment: I've lowered the iptables and it still not working

Answer (score 1):

The important line in the startup output is here:

```
1477788244: Using default config.
```

This says that mosquitto is using it's built in config (only listen on 1883 for native MQTT traffic) and not even reading your config file.

If you just start mosquitto with no command line options this is what is uses, it will not look for a config file in /etc/mosquitto/.

You need to explicitly tell mosquitto where it's config file with the `-c` option.

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Depending on how you installed mosquitto you may need to edit the scripts that automatically start it on boot. This is probably in here: /etc/init.d/mosquitto